# QDataStream not increasing position of QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, qt5, qdatastream

When I write raw network bytes to a QDataStream object repeatedly, the QDataStream never increases the write position of the underlying QByteArray.

Here's the code:

```
QByteArray recvBuf;
int bytePosition = 0;

void init( ){
    recvBuf = QByteArray( 240 * 10, Qt::Uninitiliazed );
}

void receiveAppend( ){    
    QByteArray buffer( 240, Qt::Uninitialized );
    QDataStream datastream( recvBuf, QIODevice::WriteOnly );
    datastream.setByteOrder( QDataStream::LittleEndian );

    if( udpSocket->readDataGram( buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &ip, &port ){
        datastream.device().seek( bytePosition );
        datastream.writeRawData( buffer.data(), buffer.size() );
        bytePosition += 240;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

The code works fine on Linux Mint 18 64Bit. But it's not working on Windows 10 64Bit.
I'm using Qt Creator 4.3.1 with Qt 5.9.1.

Comment: Why do you think you need (or want) to seek within the `QIODevice` whilst using `QDataStream`?  Just let the `QDataStream` do its thing as per the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html).  Sorry if I've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: On the Linux machine it works with or without seeking the position, while on Win10 both attempts do not work. The seek call was a try to get it working on Win eather without success. Why are those functions behaving different on Win/Linux?

Comment: Yes, seeking is only needed when you did manipulations on your `QIODevice` directly, so only when changing the position of the stream.